# Semifinite measure and spectral theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space (not necessary separable).

**Spectral Theorem:** Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be two commuting normal operators, then there exists a measure space $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$,
two functions $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in L^\infty(\mu)$ and a unitary operator $U:H\longrightarrow L^2(\mu)$, such that each $A_k$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $\varphi_k$, $k=1,2$. i.e.
$$UA_kU^*f=\varphi_kf,\;\forall f\in H,\,k=1,2.$$

> Is $\mu$ semifinite? i.e. for each $E \in \mathcal{E}$ with $\mu(E) = \infty$ , there exists $F \subset E$ and $F \in \mathcal{E}$ and $0 < \mu(F) < \infty$.

If $H$ is a separable complex Hilbert space, then $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and so $\mu$ is semifinite.

Comment: If $\mu$ has an infinite atom, then every $L^2$ function must vanish on that set, so it might as well not be there at all.  This suggests that you should be able to replace $\mu$ by its [semifinite part](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192399/let-x-mathcal-m-mu-be-a-measure-space-and-mu-0-the-semifinite-part-of) and get the same $L^2$ space, though I have not checked the details.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link: I meant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393985/the-semifinite-portion-of-a-measure-mu

Comment: @NateEldredge When we remplace $\mu$ by its semifinite part that doen't mean that $\mu$ is semifinite. Do you agree with me?

Comment: What I am asserting is that there always *exists* a semifinite measure satisfying the given properties.  Of course, there will always exist non-semifinite ones as well (take any such measure and if it's semifinite then consider a space with one additional point that has measure infinity).  My suspicion is that you can prove there's a semifinite one by saying "let $\mu$ be a measure satisfying the conclusion of the spectral theorem; if it is not semifinite, let $\mu_0$ be its semifinite part and then $\mu_0$ satisfies."  But I can't quite finish the proof of this.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes I understand and thank. The answer of Nik Weaver says that $\mu$ is localizable but I don't understand very well the difference between localizable and semifinite.

Comment: Every localizable measure is semifinite.  But Nik doesn't mean that $\mu$ **is** localizable, rather that it **can be taken** localizable, i.e. there always exists a localizable measure satisfying the theorem.  (The same applies to your last sentence in your question: it should say that if $H$ is separable then $\mu$ **can be taken** $\sigma$-finite.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for your details. If we replace $\mu$ by its  semifinite part, where is the problem in order to finish the proof? Thank you.

Comment: Let $\mu_0$ be the semifinite part of $\mu$.  Consider the "identity map" from $L^2(\mu)$ to $L^2(\mu_0)$.  I think I can show that it's well defined and is an isometry.  What's not so clear is how to show that it is surjective.  A function in $L^2(\mu_0)$ may be nonzero on some set which is an infinite atom for $\mu$, hence not in $L^2(\mu)$.  One needs to show it is possible to modify it on a $\mu_0$-null set so as to fix this, and I can't see how to do that.

Comment: @NateEldredge If I understand very well your comment, the problem is how to show that
 $$L^2(\mu)"=" L^2(\mu_1)?$$

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Let me explain why.

Let $v \in E$ be any nonzero vector. Then define $E_0$ to be the closure of the set of vectors of the form $p(A_1,A_1^*, A_2, A_2^*)v$ where $p$ is a complex polynomial. By restricting $p$ to have rational coefficients you can see that $E_0$ is separable. Now the point is that $A_1E_0 \subseteq E_0$ and $A_1E_0^\perp \subseteq E_0^\perp$, and similarly for $A_1^*$, $A_2$, and $A_2^*$. I.e., $E_0$ is a "reducing" subspace. Now you can Zornicate and get a family of mutually orthogonal separable subspaces $E_\alpha$, each of which is reducing for $A_1$ and $A_2$, and which span all of $E$. Apply the spectral theorem separately on each $E_\alpha$.

This shows you something even stronger than semifiniteness --- it shows you that $\mu$ is *localizable*: the measure space can be decomposed into a disjoint family of finite measure subsets, such that the measure of any set is the sum of the measures of its intersections with the members of this family.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand why $A_1E_0 \subseteq E_0$ and $A_1E_0^\perp \subseteq E_0^\perp$?

Comment: Well, these are exercises. $E_0$ is the smallest subspace which is closed in norm and closed under application of $A_1$, $A_1^*$, $A_2$, and $A_2^*$.

Comment: Thank you. I think that a localizable measure is not in general $\sigma$-finite. Do you agree with me?

Comment: No, for example counting measure on any set is localizable. It is a generalization of $\sigma$-finiteness to the nonseparable setting. [Here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/~nweaver/localizable.pdf) is a little primer on localizablility for you (from a book of mine which is in press).

Comment: To be pedantic, I guess we should say that $\mu$ *can be taken* localizable.  There is not a unique $\mu$ satisfying the theorem, and there will certainly exist such $\mu$ that are not semifinite.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was about to say that - didn't want to be pedantic...

Comment: @NikWeaver Could you please give me a reference to cite it in a paper? In the paper the Hilbert space is not necessarely separable. I want to use the spectral theorem and I want to say that the measure $\mu$ can be taken semifinite but I don't find any references to cite it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student: I would just say "it is standard".  If you really want a reference, you're going to have to go to the library and search through some books until you find it. Could be in Dunford & Schwarz, or in Reed & Simon, or Kadison-Ringrose, or Takesaki.

Comment: @NikWeaver thank you. I can  say in  my  paper  that the  measure  can  be  taken semifinite without citing a reference?

Comment: @Student: I would just say "it is standard". The argument I gave is very standard stuff.

Comment: @NikWeaver In all references which I find $H$ is assumed to be separable. I hope that if you find a reference which contains the proof in a general cae ( $H$ is not separable) the tell me in order to cite it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Student: I told you where to look.  I understand you want me to do the work for you, but I'm not going to.

Comment: @NikWeaver You misunderstand me. I look at you references  but i don't  find  what i look for.

Answer (score 1):

If we replace $\mu$ by its semifinite part $\mu_1$ defined as
$$
\mu_{1}(E) = \sup\{\mu(A) \mid A \subseteq E \text{ measurable, } \mu(A)< \infty\} \quad \text{for }E \in \mathcal{E},
$$
we have by the following answer ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296045/identity-map-between-l2-mu-and-l2-mu-rm-sf?noredirect=1&lq=1)):
 $$L^2(\mu)"=" L^2(\mu_1).$$

Thus $\mu$ can be taken semifinite measure.