# References for the Spectral Theorem ( Multiplication Operator Form)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be two commuting self-adjoint (or normal) operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $E$, then there exists a measure space $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$,
two functions $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\in L^\infty(\mu)$ and a unitary operator $U:E\longrightarrow L^2(\mu)$, such that each $A_k$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $\varphi_k$, $k=1,2$. i.e.
$$UA_kU^*f=\varphi_kf,\;\forall f\in E,\,k=1,2.$$

It is well known that if $E$ is **separable** then $\mu$ can be taken $\sigma$-finite.

> Now if $E$ is assumed to be not necessarily separable, according to this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294621/semifinite-measure-and-spectral-theorem), $\mu$ can be taken [localizable](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Enweaver/localizable.pdf).
>
> Does anyone have an exact reference?

Thanks.

Comment: If, assitionally,  $A_1,A_2$ are bounded, then this is a special case of Gelfand-Naimark theorem on  commutative Banach algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see for example section 1.4 - spectral theorem II(1.47) - in the book "A course in abstract harmonic analysis" by "Gerald B. Folland".

Comment: Thank you for the reference but Theorem 1.47(Spectral Theorem II) only concerns a single operator T and I'm interesting with a commuting pair (or even tuple) of operators.

Comment: Are you sure! The theorem is about a commutative $C^*$algebra, and this is more general than your case, it is sufficient to consider the $C^*$-algebra generated by your two operators $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Meisam Soleimani Malekan answer, we have the follwoing theorem

[image]

---

[image]